# Better way to export data from one database to another (SQLSever)

Tags: sql, sql-server, flat-file

I'm importing a big flat file (about 400.000 rows and 255+ columns) into SQL Server Management Studio through the `import wizard`.

To get the right variables I use `Suggest types`, but I have found that I need to search through all the rows to get the right variable types. It takes a very long time. Is there a way to avoid this or do it faster?

Furthermore, my real goal is to transfer data from one sql server database to another on another computer. I do this by exporting it as a flat file. But maybe this is stupid since I lose the information about the correct format?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Script with data in SQL Server 2008 and later. It will copy all the information to the related database. In the generated script you might change database name if new database needed on other computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Copy one database to another database](http://okayguru.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/copy-one-database-to-another-database.html):

> There are several ways to do this, below are two options:
>
> **Option 1**
>
> - Right click on the database you want to copy
> - Choose 'Tasks' > 'Generate scripts'
> - 'Select specific database objects'
> - Check 'Tables'
> - Mark 'Save to new query window'
> - Click 'Advanced'
> - Set 'Types of data to script' to 'Schema and data'
> - Next, Next
>
> You can now run the generated query on the new database.
>
> **Option 2**
>
> - Right click on the database you want to copy
> - 'Tasks' > 'Export Data'
> - Next, Next
> - Choose the database to copy the tables to
> - Mark 'Copy data from one or more tables or views'
> - Choose the tables you want to copy
> - Finish

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried option 2 for a start, and I managed to export the tables from the database. But how do I import it on the other computer. I have copied the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files to the new computer, and I have tried using 'Tasks' > 'Import data', but I can't see where I can specify the location of the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files.

Comment: please check the sql server installed file location..
Mark answer or upvote if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Backup your database and restores it on the other server (*the tager server must be equal or higher version*) or simply copy the database files to other server and attached it (*when copying database files, you must ensures that either you have detached the database or stop the sql server service*).